# MS Excel - showing restricted time values in y axis

Tags: excel

To compute the travel time (across two points) over a period of time, I was logging the time at which I crossed the sub-points between the two main points. My ultimate aim was to prepare a line chart which would show the trend of the journeys, and then find out where I have lost time and where I have gained.

My time entries are in the below format

```
Day 1|Day 2
09:55|09:35 
10:01|09:37
10:06|09:42
10:09|09:45
10:12|09:49
10:15|09:51
10:22|09:58
10:28|10:08
10:35|10:18
10:38|10:21
10:48|10:31
```

I drew the chart with the time series appearing on the y axis (with journey points on the x axis). But Excel has some logic to determine which time values should be shown in the y axis. How can I force excel to only show the time values which I want to be seen? For example in the above case I actually need time stamps like ;

```
09:00
09:15
09:30
09:45
10:00
10:15
10:30
10:45
11:00
```

How can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. On the Axis there is a provision to set the Min, Max values, and Major and Minor points on the axis. 
For the Min and Max values, divide the hours you wish to see by 24. Example, if the starting time should be 9AM, then *9/24 = 0.375* should be given as the Min value. If 12 noon should be the max value then *12/24 = 0.500* should be given as the Max value. For the Major point, in case the intervals have to be of 15 mins the formula to be used is *(15/60)/24 = 0.01041*.